# why in React can you express a variable inside an html element without using the template literal sintax?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, template-literals

I'm following and reading a bunch of courses on React, but I'm confused, sometimes I see using the template literal notation to express variables inside html elements, such as *p* and *h* elements, some other times for the same elements there's no such use. An example of this from the [ReactJS documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html):

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>You clicked {this.state.count} times</p>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })}>
          Click me
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Why the expression inside the *p* tag is not written like this?

```
<p>`You clicked ${this.state.count} times`</p>
```

Comment: You are not doing `<button>\`Click me\`</button>` either, so why would you expect that text content needs to be inclosed in back ticks?

Comment: Hi @felix-kling, I thought that being .js files, I would have just needed normal JS sintax. I am honestly still confused about why the need to respect the JSX sintax if it's a .js file, I suppose I need to spend some time reading about JSX to dissipate my doubts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JSX, JavaScript *expressions* are always delimited by `{` `}` brackets. Eg

```
{this.state.count}
{() => this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })}
```

Unless you use brackets, you can't use JavaScript expressions - you can only write plain text. That's just how the syntax was designed.

You *could* use a template literal for the `<p>` content if you wanted, but template literals are JS expressions, so you'd need brackets around the whole contents of the `<p>`:

```
<p>{`You clicked ${this.state.count} times`}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you CertainPerformance, I completely missed the part that React uses JSX, about which I was not aware.

Answer (score 2):

The template literal syntex is only available inside the javaScript area of the code so you can oly use it inside `{}`

So in your case it would be done like this.

```
<p>{`You clicked ${this.state.count} times`}</p>
```

But in this case it is really simpler to do it without the template literal like this

```
<p>You clicked {this.state.count} times</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need template strings in react to display a variable if you are just printing its value of a number or a string for example.

You don't need template strings to display a value from an array or object

```
{obj.key}
{array[3])
```

The above examples will both print without literals

The same does not apply to Boolean values if for some reason you needed to display the words true or false.

I think people just get used to using them so continue to do so in react but there isn't any need in most cases